# Exception specifications and templates

Tags: c++, c++17

The following snippet is rejected by clang:

```
template <typename T> void foo() noexcept {}
template <typename T> void bar() throw() {}
template void foo<int>();
template void bar<int>();
```

With `clang++ -std=c++1z -c` I get:

```
compat.ii:3:15: error: explicit instantiation of 'foo' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data member
template void foo<int>();
              ^
compat.ii:1:28: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'void () noexcept' against 'void ()'
template <typename T> void foo() noexcept {}
                           ^
compat.ii:4:15: error: explicit instantiation of 'bar' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data member
template void bar<int>();
              ^
compat.ii:2:28: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'void () throw()' against 'void ()'
template <typename T> void bar() throw() {}
                           ^
2 errors generated.
```

gcc trunk accepts the code with `-std=c++1z`.
Which compiler is right?

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ORbvh5K070lXWt7U)

Comment: I presume Clang works if you add `noexcept` to `void foo<int>` and `throw()` to `void bar<int>`?

Comment: My trunk gcc rejects such code. So does wandbox's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround for Clang is to specify the exception *spec*:

```
template <typename T> void foo() noexcept {}
template <typename T> void bar() throw() {}
template void foo<int>() noexcept;
template void bar<int>() throw();
```

Though, starting from C++17, exception specifications are now part of a function's signature, it is not required for explicit instantiations. To quote [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Explanation):

> The noexcept-specification is a part of the function type and may
>   appear as part of any function declarator. since C++17

The longer version from the standard: (Latest draft) [[except.spec/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#5) ...(emphasis mine).

> If any declaration of a function has an exception-specification that
>   is not a noexcept-specification allowing all exceptions, all
>   declarations, including the definition and any explicit
>   specialization, of that function shall have a compatible
>   exception-specification. If any declaration of a pointer to function,
>   reference to function, or pointer to member function has an
>   exception-specification, all occurrences of that declaration shall
>   have a compatible exception-specification. If a declaration of a
>   function has an implicit exception specification, other declarations
>   of the function shall not specify an exception-specification. **In an
>   explicit instantiation an exception-specification may be specified,
>   but is not required.** If an exception-specification is specified in an
>   explicit instantiation directive, it shall be compatible with the
>   exception-specifications of other declarations of that function. A
>   diagnostic is required only if the exception-specifications are not
>   compatible within a single translation unit.

Comment: Well, it says: "In an explicit instantiation an exception-specification may be specified, but is not required.". Only when it is used and not compatible then a diagnostic is required in a single CU. 
So it looks more like a Clang bug to me.